# The string literal is longer than 4000 characters

Tags: string, oracle, oracle11g, varchar, clob

I have one function which basically consume XML as input and do the next step.

I'm passing XML from one statement but it is giving error

**"The string literal is longer than 4000 characters"**

**Function**

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_ADD_TEST(P_XML_DATA CLOB) RETURN NUMBER AS
xmlContent xmlType;
RESP_XML XMLTYPE;

o xmlType;
c xmlType;


BEGIN
--xmlContent := xmlType(xmlData);
raise_application_error('-20003',P_XML_DATA);
-- Further steps


RETURN 1;
END F_ADD_TEST;
```

**Statement**

```
Select F_ADD_TEST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncReceiveDelivery xmlns:ln="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
    <DataArea>
        <ReceiveDelivery>
            <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>100_ZHA005270</ID>
                </DocumentID>
            <WarehouseLocation>
                <ID>W_ZHF12S</ID>
            </WarehouseLocation>
        </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
        <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
            <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
            <ItemID>
                <ID>24101600PA02435</ID>
                <RevisionID>S000</RevisionID>
            </ItemID>
            <ReceivedQuantity>1</ReceivedQuantity>
            <ServiceOrder>KRH000033</ServiceOrder>
        </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
            <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
            <ItemID>
                <ID>24101600PA04407</ID>
                <RevisionID>S000</RevisionID>
            </ItemID>
            <ReceivedQuantity>4</ReceivedQuantity>
            <ServiceOrder>KRH000033</ServiceOrder>
        </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
    </ReceiveDelivery>
</DataArea>
</SyncReceiveDelivery>') from dual;
```

If the XML content is huge I'm getting error

**"The string literal is longer than 4000 characters"**

I have changed datatype from Varchar to clob but still the same. Please help me on this.

Comment: Where is the XML string coming from - are you copying and pasting it from a file which Oracle could read directly, for instance? [Or through SQL\*Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24164721/266304)?  Otherwise there are lots of examples of splitting a long string up and building a CLOB from the parts.

Comment: XML is coming from one middle ware software I cant the split the XML. For understanding I have prepared here as a statement,

Comment: So bind the value as a CLOB from the middleware layer rather than as a string? Hopefully you are using prepared statements and bind variables, not constructing a new statement with the literal value each time, right?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT ... FROM dual;`, Try PL/SQL `Declare
 res number;
begin
 res := F_ADD_TEST('...');`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `'...'` is still a text literal but [in PL/SQL it can hold 32,767 bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems026.htm) so this may just be moving the issue to a larger limit that the OP is still going to exceed.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `'a value'` is a text literal and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) states:

> Text literals have properties of both the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` datatypes:
>
> - Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the datatype `CHAR` by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.
> - A text literal can have a maximum length of 4000 bytes.

So your code is:

```
SELECT SOME_FUNCTION( 'A text literal which cannot be more than 4000 bytes' ) FROM DUAL
```

If you want to have more than 4000 bytes in a String in SQL then you cannot use a text literal and will have to pass in a CLOB via a bind parameter (either using PL/SQL or another language/middleware) or something like modifying your code to take a file name and load the XML from a file.

```
SELECT F_ADD_TEST( :bindparameter ) FROM DUAL;
```